# assign property value by another property and change property value

Tags: javascript

assign property value by another property and change it dynamically

```
     var obj = {
          name : null,
          id : null
       };

    var result = obj.name;
   console.log(result); // null

   obj.name = 'myName'
   console.log(result); // null 
  // here i want to show 'myname'
```

Comment: You cannot create a reference between two strings or any primitive type.

Answer (score 1):

In `result`, store the reference of `obj` instead of storing the value of `obj.name`. Your code `var result = obj.name` store the value `null` and is not a reference to object.

```js
var obj = {
    name : null,
    id : null
};

var result = obj;
console.log(result); // null

obj.name = 'myName'
console.log(result); 

console.log(result.name);
```

You can also first change the `obj` `name` property and then assign it's value to your `result`, so that changed property value gets reflected.

```js
var obj = {
    name : null,
    id : null
};

obj.name = 'myName';

var result = obj.name;

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

`obj.name` is a primitive value, therefore the change to `obj.name` doesn't modify the `result`

You could set the result to be a reference for `obj` changes to have an effect on the `result`

```js
var obj = {
    name : null,
    id : null
};

var result = obj; // create reference
obj.name = 'hi';  // modify original object

console.log(result.name);
```